# Need .HTACCESS code to decode %3Fand %3D

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have installed "custom-permalinks" plugin for wordpress

It is working well but I have problem with `%3F` (<kbd>?</kbd>) and `%3D` (<kbd>=</kbd>)

Instead of this :
`?file=kop444.php` as url  (444 stand for any other number)
It make it `%3Ffile%3Dkop444.php`

I understand [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) can help - but I have not found code reported to be working

Here are the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What do you have in your .htaccess at the moment?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress